# Abstract factory pattern and HikariCP

Tags: java, mysql, design-patterns, jdbc, hikaricp

I'm currently using a pool connection(Hikari) and an abstract factory pattern to implement my MySQL queries in Java like this:

MySqlFactoryDAO.java

```
public class MySqlFactoryDAO extends FactoryDAO {

   private static HikariDataSource connPool_;

   public static Connection createConnection() throws SQLException {

      if (connPool_ == null) {
         // Load database configuration
         PropertiesFile props = FactoryConfig.getConfig().getDatabaseProperties();

         connPool_ = new HikariDataSource();
         connPool_.setJdbcUrl(props.getString(Params.DB_URL,""));
         connPool_.setUsername(props.getString(Params.DB_USER,"root"));
         connPool_.setPassword(props.getString(Params.DB_PASSWORD,"root"));
      }
      return connPool_.getConnection();
   }

   //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

   public ProductDAO getProductDAO() {
      return new ProductMySQLFactoryDAO();
   }
}
```

ProductMySQLFactoryDAO.java

```
public class ProductMySQLFactoryDAO implements ProductDAO {

   public int insertProduct(String name) {  
      ...
      Connection conn = MySqlFactoryDAO.createConnection();
      ...
   }    
}
```

I was wondering if this code is thread safe and I think that there is a problem at the time of initialization of `coonPool_`. I have read things like "Initialization-on-demand_holder_idiom" in wikipedia but I am not sure about it. Does anyone have a better implementation of this to solve this problem or just a better new one?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not thread-safe. Two threads might call `createConnection()` concurrently, both see the pool as `null`, and both create a new DataSource.

The method needs to be synchronized. Or the pool must be created at class initializing time:

```
private static final HikariDataSource DATA_SOURCE = createDataSource();
```

Your `connPool_` field should be private, too.

Comment: Yes, It should be private, I copy it wrong. I thought about a synchronized method but it think a synchronized here reduces the performance a lot.